# how to match user name and password in angular js....?

Tags: javascript, angular

I designed one html page which is normal log in page which included user name and password. I want to match values (NOT FROM THE DATA BASE) from the JavaScript page by clicking on sign in button.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad idea, it's very insecure to do that. Use some type of server side language to hardcode the values or the best is to use a database.

BUT if you're just testing and want to compare values. You could do something like this...

HTML

```
<input type="text"  #username>
<input type="password"  #password>
<button type="submit" (click) = 'signIn(username.value, password.value)'>Add</button>
```

Angular component

```
signIn(username:string, password:string) {
    if(username =="your string here" && password=="your string here")
    {
        ///execute your code
    }
}
```

Or just bind the values of username and password to variables in your component and compare when you submit.